# Recyclerview: edit the layout parameters of the views without inflating

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

This is my code inside my Adapter:

```
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    Button b = new Button(parent.getContext());
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AddExerciseActivity mActivity = (AddExerciseActivity) view.getContext();
            mActivity.startExercise(view);
        }
    });
    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(b);
    return vh;
}

public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder vh, int position){
    vh.mButton.setText(mDataset[position][0]);
    vh.mButton.setTag(mDataset[position][1]);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = vh.mButton.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
    vh.mButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

As you can see I do not inflate anything in my `onCreateViewHolder`. I just take a normal button, no custom xml involved. If I had picked a custom XML it would be easy to achieve what I want: `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`. How do I achieve fill_parent in java? You can see how I have tried it in my `onBindViewHolder`. I have understood why this leads to a runtime error with a "null object reference": my `getLayoutParams` doesn't work because the view has not been assigned to a viewgroup yet (correct?). When does the layout manager (it is the layout manager who does this, is that right?) assign the view to a viewgroup (which I assume is the recyclerview) and how can I get my button after that has happened in order to edit its LayoutParams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are probably hooks for you to take a peek at an item view that is being attached to the `RecyclerView` ([RecyclerView#OnChildAttachStateChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener) maybe, but I haven't looked into it), I think it would be best just to assign the layout params in `onCreateViewHolder()` like this:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Button b= new Button(parent.getContext());
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp =
        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    return new ItemViewHolder(b);
}
```

The layout params would then be processed when the view item is added to the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: ah thank you, both very satisfying solutions. regarding the second: is there a case where the layout manager needs to set layout params for the view and will the manager then just override what I've done in `onCreateViewHolder` ? or would it fetch existing layout params first and then edit them? I think I will go with the first solution, looks like `onChildViewAttachedToWindow` is the right hook that I'm looking for ("Called when a view is attached to the RecyclerView"). thank you!